# How do I request two accounts to be merged?

Tags: support, faq

I have created another account by mistake. How do I request the accounts to be merged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community moderators cannot merge accounts anymore. You need to ask to Stack Exchange stuff to do it.

Click on *contact us*, the link you find on the footer.

[image: screenshot]

On the next form, for *What can we help you for?* select *I need to merge user  profiles*.

> [image: screenshot]

Fill the other fields, and click on *submit*.

Keep in mind that, to ask to merge two accounts, you need to be logged-in with one of them, and you need to click on *contact us* on the site where you have both the accounts.